# Open folder contents into directory above

Tags: php, file, directory

In this example folder, I need to move all the contents of sub into the above directory using PHP in the move.php file.

```
▼ dir
  - move.php
  ▼ sub
    - a.txt
    - b.txt
```

After move.php is run, the files should look like this:

```
▼ dir
  - move.php
  - a.txt
  - b.txt
```

Thanks.

Comment: So... what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you a hint.

1. Use `php` **[file_get_contents('file_dir')](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents)** to read the file into a string
2. Use `php` **[file_put_contents('file_dir')](https://www.php.net/file_put_contents)** to create the file
3. Also use `php` **[unlink('file_dir')](https://www.php.net/unlink)** function to delete a file if necessary
4. If you need to remove directory, use `php` **[rmdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php)** function.

If you do not need to access the files, you can just use `php` **[copy($source, $dest)](https://www.php.net/copy)** function to copy your files from one directory to another. Then you can delete them from old directory.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I now realize that this was a multi-step problem

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at php `scandir()` function to scan your sub-directory and move files from it to your current directory.